# Is there a firefox add-on that will allow me to "hide" my bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, bookmarks

I'd like to essentially "hide" my bookmarks and reload them each time I start the browser.  Is there any Firefox plugin that can do this?

Essentially my use case would be:

- open firefox, see that there are no bookmarks
- in the menu for an add-on, click "sync"
- all my bookmarks appear
- add some bookmarks, delete some, whatever
- close firefox
- repeat

Is there anything like this?  Is there a way I could use xmarks to do something like this?

Comment: I can't possibly this of the reason you'd want to do this rather than just, yaknow, having your bookmarks there, but maybe if you explained the purpose, it might help somebody to provide a solution.

Comment: Well, let's say someone else is going to be using my computer, and I don't want them to see my bookmarks.  (Yes, I'm assuming that they won't be able to figure out how to load them.)  I also want them to be convenient enough for me to use when I want them, so I don't want to just "hide" everything in delicious and be done with it.

Comment: @Shinrai, obviously the purpose is to make sure other people can't see his bookmarks. Maybe he has a webmd article on how to relieve anal fissures bookmarked that he doesn't want other people to know about. That's "nunya". Just provide an answer if you know of any.

Comment: @RyanM. - "I don't want other people to see my bookmarks" is very different from, say, "I have a bad habit of wasting time on certain sites and I'm trying to bury them so I can't access them as easily".  It's not OBVIOUS at all, so please tone down the hostility.  But, since Jer has said that indeed the goal is hiding them, why not just make a different user account for whoever will be using the machine (I think Firefox bookmarks are account specific)?  Or have them use a different browser entirely.

Comment: Your examples ARE very different, but of course, that's not what the poster was requesting :) Reading for the win.

Comment: @RyanM. - He said WHAT he wanted to do, not why.  Very often on this site, we see people asking a question where they've thought of one way to do something and ask in that context, but when the reason for the question comes out it turns out there's a totally different method that's way better for what they're trying to accomplish.  It's ALWAYS best to clarify your intention with a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach, IMO, if somebody else is going to be using your machine and this is a privacy concern, is just to make them use a different user account.

You also have the option of [setting up separate Firefox profiles](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles) or having them use another browser entirely.

EDIT: It looks like [there's a plugin that will let you scramble your existing bookmarks behind a password wall](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-password/), if that's preferable for some reason.